# `Integer` as `Datum` in offchain code

Tags: plutus

In the onchain validator I used Integer type for Datum and everything was fine
but when I want to use mustPayToOtherScript tx constraint in the offchain code I get the following error:

```
 • Couldn't match expected type ‘Datum’ with actual type ‘Integer’
 • In the second argument of ‘mustPayToOtherScript’
```

Edit: offchain code

```
start :: AsContractError e => Promise () OwnerSchema e ()
start = endpoint @"start" $ \const -> do
    pkh <- pubKeyHash <$> ownPubKey
    let 
        tokenAAmount = 10000000000 
        tokenBAmount = 1000000000000
        lt = 100000000000
        value = (V.assetClassValue poolNFT 1) <>
                (V.assetClassValue tokenA tokenAAmount) <>
                (V.assetClassValue tokenB tokenBAmount)
        tx   = mustPayToTheScript (lt) value 
    ledgerTx <- submitTxConstraints poolInst' tx
    void $ awaitTxConfirmed $ txId ledgerTx
    void $ waitNSlots 1
    logInfo @String $ printf "created pool UTXO %s at validator hash %s" (show poolParams) (show $ orderBoxVH')
    return ()
```

Comment: Can you please add the `mustPayToOtherScript` code you wrote?

Comment: Sure, I am trying to create a uniswap type pool UTXO which stores the liquidity token supply in its datum (hence of Integer type)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your off-chain code is using `mustPayToTheScript` and not `mustPayToOtherScript`. It's important to note the difference, since `mustPayToTheScript` will require a datum with the type you defined in `poolInst'`, while `mustPayToOtherScript` will require a datum of type `Datum`.

So, I will assume you want to use the latter. In this case, you need to convert your variable of type `Integer` to a variable of type `Datum`. This can be easily done with `(Datum $ PlutusTx.toBuiltinData lt)`.

Assuming your logic and other components are working, your code would look like the following:

```
start :: AsContractError e => Promise () OwnerSchema e ()
start = endpoint @"start" $ \const -> do
    pkh <- pubKeyHash <$> ownPubKey
    let 
        tokenAAmount = 10000000000 
        tokenBAmount = 1000000000000
        lt = 100000000000
        value = (V.assetClassValue poolNFT 1) <>
                (V.assetClassValue tokenA tokenAAmount) <>
                (V.assetClassValue tokenB tokenBAmount)
        tx   = mustPayToOtherScript (Datum $ PlutusTx.toBuiltinData lt) value 
    ledgerTx <- submitTxConstraints poolInst' tx
    void $ awaitTxConfirmed $ txId ledgerTx
    void $ waitNSlots 1
    logInfo @String $ printf "created pool UTXO %s at validator hash %s" (show poolParams) (show $ orderBoxVH')
    return ()
```

Just so it gets easy to debug in the future, I would suggest you to create a function focused specifically in the contract and another function for handling endpoints.